# Websphere change JNDI name in EAR

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, jndi, ear

I got a legacy EJB 2 application which I deploy to Websphere 8.5. The application has dependencies, which define JNDI bindings to a DataSource in /META-INF/ejb-jar.xml and /META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml.

I'm not allowed to change the code in those dependencies and neither can I change the Websphere's config. But I could make changes to the config files in the jar files.

I want to override the effective JNDI bindings in my application. Is it possible to define a file that will be added to the Ear to override those bindings?

snippet of the ejb-jar.xml:

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1248968390265">
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/CentralDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml:

```
<session name="FooJob">
    <resource-ref name="jdbc/CentralDS" binding-name="jdbc/VeryCentralDs" />
</session>
```

Is it possible to override this JNDI name (VeryCentralDs) somewhere?

Comment: not sure what exactly you need? The web.xml resource-ref/res-ref-name is referred i your code, the ibm-web-bnd.xml is used for binding with WAS server defined JNDI resource as: web-bnd/resource-ref.name (listed in web.xml) and it's resource-ref.binding-name defined as WAS JNDI resource

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to override resource reference bindings at deployment time.  This [knowledge center article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/trun_app_instwiz.html) steps through deploying an application. Watch for the step "Map resource references to resources" which is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/udat_maprrr.html). This is where you can fill in the target JNDI name that you want the resource reference bound to.